# Feature to vibrate even the phone is in silent mode android

Tags: android, android-vibration

which will trigger vibrate in Android even the mobile is in silent mode.

On some devices, Vibrate is not working even the mobile is in General mode.

I have tried below code for vibration:

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(150, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));

} else {  
  vibrator.vibrate(150);
}
```

Have given permission within manifest also.

Is there is a way that I can do this, irrespective of mobile state(i.e General or Silent)?

Comment: Silent mode comes with vibration also.

Comment: @VivekMishra Like how does Alarm work even if the phone is in silent mode. I just need to do the same.

Comment: That mode is vibration mode. In silent mode it doesn't vibrate

Comment: @VivekMishra But anyhow this code is not working on few mobiles, like Moto X play, Vibration is not working even if the mobile is in normal mode.